# Access global variable from XMLHttpRequest onload callback

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, global-variables, closures

How do I access the `globalBuffer` variable after setting it in the `request.onload` callback? I'm learning more about closures, but don't understand why I'm unable to set the value and retrieve it after the fact. In other words, why does `console.log(globalBuffer)` return `undefined`?

```
var globalBuffer;
var context = new webkitAudioContext();

function loadSound(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    request.onload = function() {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
                // I want to set globalBuffer and retrieve it outside the function
                globalBuffer = buffer;
            }    
        );
    }
    request.send();
}

loadSound("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9e/Metallica_-_For_Whom_the_Bell_Tolls_%28song%29.ogg");

console.log(globalBuffer);
```

---

Edit:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/levivoelz/pen/ikICf?editors=001)

Comment: you can reach it from anywhere after you set it. try pasting your last line into the console once the code runs and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Tried that– `globalBuffer` comes back as `undefined`. If I run `console.log(globalBuffer)` inside the `onload` function, it returns the object, which makes sense, asynchronously. I figured `onload` would fire after everything had loaded, and then I'd be ok to set the variable and retrieve it for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadSound` is asynchronous method, and `console.log` is synchronous - is not waiting till `loadSound` will end. `globalBuffer` is declarated with value undefined and this value is returned without waiting for finish `loadSound`

proof of concept how it can be solved:

```
function loadSound(url, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    return callback('loaded song from: ' + url)
  }, 1000);
}

loadSound('url to sound clip', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

`setTimeout` is for simulating asynchronous action - if data is available - callback function is calling.

Comment: I see how that works, and am able to access it through the callback function, but I'm still unable to access it globally. Check out this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/levivoelz/pen/ikICf?editors=001).

Comment: Still console.log runs before loadSound finish execution. To check this set some value to globalBuffer in first line and than chack what console.log will return.